# Mapstruct: map using literal parameters

Tags: mapstruct

Here my class:

```java
public class QdCFPresenter {

    private Long id;
    private Long codi;
    private String name;
```

Is there any way to update a target object using a single literal parameter?

Something like that:

```java
@Mapper
public interface QdCFMapper {

    public QdCFPresender mapTo(QdCFPresenter target, String name);

}
```

I'd like mapstruct generates something like:

```java
public interface QdCFMapperImpl {

    public QdCFPresender mapTo(QdCFPresenter target, String name) {
        target.setName(name);
        return target;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapStruct has the concept of update mappings using `@MappingTarget`.

In your example you'll need to od something like:

```
@Mapper
public interface QdCFMapper {

    public QdCFPresender mapTo(@MappingTarget QdCFPresenter target, String name);

}
```

Then MapStruct will do its thing and generate what you need.